# GNAT.Serial_Communications how to convert Stream_Element_Array

Tags: ada, serial-communication, gnat

I try to write a small communication program with an Arduino using the `GNAT.Serial_Communications` package.

Establishing the communication to the Arduino works fine. 
I'm using the `Serial_Communications.Read()` function to get the Information. Now I want to convert the data stored in a `Stream_Element_Array` into an `Integer`.

I tried the `Integer'Value()` function but it's not working and I receive the error message: `expected type "Standard.String"`

Using `String'Value()` results in: `prefix of value attribute must be scalar type`.

I can't find any information about the conversion of a `Stream_Element_Array`.

```
  Serial_Communications.Open
  (Port => Port,
   Name => Port_Name);

  Serial_Communications.Set
  (Port      => Port,
   Rate      => Serial_Communications.B115200,
   Bits      => Serial_Communications.CS8,
   Stop_Bits => Serial_Communications.One,
   Parity    => Serial_Communications.Even);


  Serial_Communications.Read(Port  => Port,
                             Buffer => Buffer,
                             Last   => Last);

  Int_value := Integer'Value(String'Value(Buffer(1)));

  Serial_Communications.Close(Port => Port);
```

Comment: Please show us what it is that you’re sending to the Arduino: e.g. `"12345"` or `0x30`,  `0x39` or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen in [the ARM](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-13-1.html), a `Stream_Element` is a modular type and should by the way already be cast to an [`Integer` type](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-4.html).

Something like

```ada
Int_value := Integer(Buffer(Buffer'First));
```

should directly work but I didn't test anything ;)

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Comment: Great ! Don't forget to mark your question as answered by clicking on the tick left to the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

The type `GNAT.Serial_Communications.Serial_Port` is an extension to `Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type`:

```
type Serial_Port is new Ada.Streams.Root_Stream_Type with private;
```

This means that you can use it as a stream and therefore use the `Read` attribute (see [ARM 13.13](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-13.html) for details). Furthermore, I would recommend to use an integer type from the `Interfaces` package rather than the Ada `Integer` type as all Ada integer types are defined by a minimal range to be supported and have no mandated storage size (see [ARM 3.5.4 (21)](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-4.html#p21) and [ARM B.2](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-B-2.html) for details).

The following example might help:

```
with Interfaces;
with GNAT.Serial_Communications;

procedure Main is

   package SC renames GNAT.Serial_Communications;

   Port_Name :         SC.Port_Name := "COM1";
   Port      : aliased SC.Serial_Port;

   Int_Value : Interfaces.Integer_8;

begin

   SC.Open
     (Port => Port,
      Name => Port_Name);

   SC.Set
     (Port      => Port,
      Rate      => SC.B115200,
      Bits      => SC.CS8,
      Stop_Bits => SC.One,
      Parity    => SC.Even); 

   --  Check Interfaces package for types other than "Integer_8".
   Interfaces.Integer_8'Read (Port'Access, Int_Value);

   SC.Close(Port => Port);

end Main;
```